# Compiling a Qt project with CMake using resources and ROS (catkin_make)

Tags: c++, qt, ros

I'm using cmake to compile a Qt project (which also uses catkin, since this is really a ROS project but I don't think the problem is related to this). Everything compiled and worked fine until I started to use images and added a qrc file to handle them. When I run cmake I get this error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/home/myname/development/ros/src/dls_gui/images/slide-groove.png', needed by `dls_gui/qrc_dls_gui.cpp'.  Stop.
```

My CMakeList file is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(dls_gui)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# catkin related
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp sensor_msgs urdf)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} include)

# source, header and resources files list
set(CPP_SOURCES src/main.cpp src/mainwindow.cpp src/basewidget.cpp src/rosQtNode.cpp src/joints_sliders.cpp src/superslider.cpp)
set(CPP_HDRS include/mainwindow.h include/basewidget.h include/rosQtNode.hpp include/joints_sliders.hpp include/superslider.hpp)
set(QRC_RESOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dls_gui.qrc)
# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package()

# Add the include directories for the Qt 5 Widgets module to
# the compile lines.
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Use the compile definitions defined in the Qt 5 Widgets module
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

# Generate headers from ui files
qt5_wrap_ui(UIS_HDRS src/mainwindow.ui)

# Generate moc files from cpp
qt5_wrap_cpp(MOC_SOURCES ${CPP_SOURCES} ${CPP_HDRS})

# Generate resources 
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES_RCC ${RESOURCE})

# Add compiler flags for building executables (-fPIE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

## Ros include dirs
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(dls_gui ${CPP_SOURCES} ${UIS_HDRS} ${MOC_SOURCES} ${QRC_RESOURCES})
add_executable(testRos src/testRos.cpp)
qt5_use_modules(dls_gui Widgets)

#Link the helloworld executable to the Qt 5 widgets library.
target_link_libraries(dls_gui Qt5::Widgets ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(testRos ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

the qrc file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix="/images">
    <file>images/slide-groove.png</file>
    <file>images/slide-handle.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

I'm using cmake 2.8.12.2 on an ubuntu 14.04 machine.

Comment: Try `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC OFF)`

Comment: I set it off, but at the end I just removed it. It did not do anything. At least not in my cmake version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently it was an issue with catking. I removed the build directory created by catkin, ran again catkin_make, and now it compiles.

Note: I just did a minor editing to the cmake file. I had copied the wrong one on SO.

Comment: So, please close this question (to inform other people that they shouldn't spend their time on reading of the question).

Comment: Sadly, this procedure is necessary with catkin quite often. If something does not work for a non-obvious reason, the first attempt should always be to delete the `build` and `devel` directories and run it again, as this often solves the problem :)

Comment: @llya I have to wait one more day to close it.